# CakePHP reverse routing not working as expected

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-1.3

I need several routes in my application to allow for a dynamic string to proceed the prefix.

Here's my route:

```
Router::connect('/:location/traveler/:controller/*', array('action' => 'index', 'traveler' => true, 'prefix' => 'traveler'), array('pass' => array('location')));
```

For instance, if I went to **/south/traveler/requests** it would route successfully to RequestsController::traveler_index($location = 'south').

This is what I want, but I also need HtmlHelper::link() to properly reverse route a URL array into that route.

Here's my call to HtmlHelper::link():

```
$this->Html->link('List Requests', array('controller' => 'requests', 'action' => 'index', 'location' => 'south'));
```

The prefix routing is (or should be) implied since this is being called from a view within the traveler prefix.

The URL that call spits out is:

```
http://domain.com/traveler/requests/location:south
```

Have I not done something correctly? Is there any way I can avoid creating a custom route class to properly reverse route these URL arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Removing Router::connectNamed() from routes.php, I repaired my route which was misconfigured.

The reverse route to traveler_index() worked properly using the route I listed above, but any call to any other function, like traveler_edit() would fail.

Using the route below, I was able to get it to reverse route for any action on any controller in the traveler prefix with location as a variable.

```
Router::connect('/:location/traveler/:controller/:action/*', array('traveler' => true, 'prefix' => 'traveler'), array('pass' => array('location')));
```

Now, my call to HtmlHelper::link() correctly reverse-routes my URL array:

```
$this->Html->link('Edit Details', array('controller' => 'requests', 'action' => 'edit', 'location' => 'south', 1234));
```

...reverse routes to **/south/traveler/requests/edit/1234**.

Comment: When I was hitting this problem `/south/traveler/requests/edit/1234` will work, but something like `/south/traveler/requests/edit/baggage:1234` will fail and you'll be back to `/traveler/requests/edit/location:south/baggage:1234`. The fix for this is [@deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6093728/327074) which handles reverse routing of named parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to inform the router that `location` should be a named parameter using `Router::connectNamed`. See the [Named Parameters section of the CakePHP v1.3 Book](https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html#named-parameters):

> ```
> URL: /contents/view/chapter:models/section:associations
> ```
>
> When making custom routes, a common pitfall is that using named parameters will break your custom routes. In order to solve this you should inform the Router about which parameters are intended to be named parameters. Without this knowledge the Router is unable to determine whether named parameters are intended to actually be named parameters or routed parameters, and defaults to assuming you intended them to be routed parameters. To connect named parameters in the router use Router::connectNamed().
>
> ```
> Router::connectNamed(array('chapter', 'section'));
> ```
>
> Will ensure that your chapter and section parameters reverse route correctly.

Comment: I put the following above all my routes in routes.php:

`Router::connectNamed(array('location'))`

and it still reverse routes to `http://domain.com/traveler/requests/location:south`

Comment: Now that I've been through some pain trying to figure this out, I believe this answer isn't quite correct. `location` is a *routing* parameter. The problem is that if you add a named paramter to the URL then it treats location as a named parameter too. So `['controller' => 'requests', 'action' => 'edit', 'location' => 'south', 'baggage' => 1234]` will break and fall back to `/traveler/requests/edit/location:south/baggage:1234`. However when you have this URL then you can specify `Router::connectNamed(array('baggage'))` and the array can be reverse routed correctly.